# Solving circular project dependency between C# and C++/CLI projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, circular-dependency

We have a solution with a number of projects.

In one particular case, we have two projects:
1) A C# project that does most of the work
2) A C++/CLI project that acts as a go-between to some native C++ code

The C# code calls into the C++ wrapper, all is well.

However, there is some new functionality that we are pulling in.  On the managed side of the C++ wrapper (project #2), it requires some static methods in the managed C# code that is in project #1.  However, Visual Studio will not let us mutually associate these two projects as it complains of a circular project reference.  There is no circular *class* reference however.

Is there any solution to this problem that does not require a 3rd project as an intermediary?

Comment: Compile a dll (or more than one dll) for your new functions...
Its cheating in that its it basically creating an intermediary, but its not a project.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention, we more or less don't allow binary references for our internal stuff, so it has to be a project reference in one way or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have A depend on B.  For simplicity lets say A.EXE depends on B.DLL.  Then when A initially calls B, it can give it an object of some type or interface that is defined in B and then B can turn around and call back into A at some later point.

In other words, B defines a base class or interface like "I want something that only A can do" but don't implement it.  Then let A implements it, passes it to you, and calls it.  This gets around the circular dependency without a third project.  This applies to any pair of managed projects.